# What are the possible reasons for NoClassDefFoundError when querying Environment?

Tags: android

This is the offending line of code:

`String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();`

Why does it throw NoClassDefFoundError in some rare cases (never on my development device, but on some users' devices)?

The target systems are Android 3.1 and higher, I don't know which system it crashed on.
The exact message I get from bugreport is: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.os.Environment`.

Comment: While ago I was getting the same exception for `Log` class and I start thinking that it's maybe some kind of bug maybe in Android or some manufacturer. I have no other explanation.